# Voltage regulator LMR33630 doesn't work, asking for circuit review

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb-design, voltage-regulator, buck, overheat

I've put LMR33630ADDAR voltage regulator into a PCB with this circuit:
[image]

It's slightly different from the example from datasheet:
[image]
PG isn't connected, CFF capacitor absent and feedback resistors are 10k vs. 2.49k. I see no issues with these difference since resistor divider is the same for expected 5V output and PG pin may be not used according to datasheet:

> Open drain power-good flag output. Connect to suitable voltage supply through a
> current limiting resistor. High = power OK, low = power bad. Flag pulls low when EN =
> Low. Can be left open when not used

And the same for CFF capacitor:

> In some cases, a feedforward capacitor can be used across R FBT to improve the load transient response or
> improve the loop-phase margin. This is especially true when values of RFBT > 100 kΩ are used

**So, in result the circuit doesn't work - if I supply 12V input, I see 5.6V on BOOT and VCC pins (which is expected) but 0V on SW pin. I have no idea what's wrong. Furthermore, If I supply 5V, the LMR33630 starts heating to the burning point.**

Here is also part of the PCB, probably the issue is in placement:

[image]

[image]

Would appreciate help of experts in this area since it's my first design of voltage regulation circuit

Comment: Do you have a fast oscilloscope, and do you see signs of instability? I'm looking at the datasheet and it has a suggested layout in fig 10.2; you may want to compare yours with theirs to try to get some insight.

Comment: @nanofarad unfortunatelly don't have an oscilloscope. My layout differs from that in reference due to PCB limitations, but still I tried to follow the rules. As I understand, bad layout would cause offsets in voltage or similar instability. But in my case it doesn't work at all. If no other reasons will appear, maybe the chip is counterfeit (it's completely assembled by JLCPCB)

Comment: The only other difference I see - the heat-sink pad in the ref. layout is connected to ground but left not connected to anything in my case

Comment: I see below you have solved your problem, but keep in mind that your placement is suboptimal. The SW track is very very thin for no reason, and you will loose efficiency there. In case you respin this PCB, swap the L1 and C18 and make the SW track a plane.

Comment: @brigadir The heatsink pad should be connected to a large plane for thermal dissipation; leaving it connected to nothing provides no benefit.

Comment: @Hearth sure! In my case it was soldered but isolated

Comment: @Vladimir Cravero good point, thanks. I missed that detail about 5V track width. Regarding swapping the induction and capacitor - why it would work better? As far as I know the induction should be placed far away from the chip and the feedback loop.

Comment: @brigadir That still doesn't give much benefit, even if it's not an electrical connection.

Comment: @brigadir regarding your follow up question, that is not something that can fit in the comments here as there are several reasons that cannot be articulated in such a small space in my opinion. Feel free to ask another question and I will be happy to help, or someone else will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr33630.pdf?ts=1682492317538&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLMR33630) says that the exposed thermal pad is also analog ground.

[image]

The pad in the image appears to be floating.

The images are a bit confusing The top and bottom layers look identical with the parts on the bottom layer. This is unconventional and could lead to mirror image footprints. Note that red is considered the top layer and blue the bottom layer. While parts can be placed on the bottom layer, the footprints msut be placed as mirro image unless the view is inverted.

Comment: Good point regarding thermal pad, I'll check it soon. Regarding layers - sorry for misconception. Both images show top layer, the latter one is just 3D render for better visualization. Bottom layer doesn't contain anything useful

Comment: Thank you RussellH, it was the reason of the issue. After soldering the thermal pad to ground all works perfectly. Unfortunately one chip has gone, it was sacrificed for the sake of learning